# how to load image in swift from URL

Tags: swift, url, uiimage, iso

I am passing a URL in string format from firebase to load an image, the url gets passed fine but the cell.articleImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UiImage(named: "issaimage")) isn't returning the picture from the url, just the placeholder image

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell") as? articlesCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()}

        let article = articleArray[indexPath.row]
        let url = URL(string: article.imageURL)!

        cell.articleImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "issaimage"))

        cell.configureCell(title: article.ArticleTitle, author: article.author, date: article.date)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier 'image'" in my cell.configureCell(title: article.ArticleTitle, author: article.author, date: article.date, image: image) function

Comment: show that part of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This code isn't allowing me to use the image variable

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

because it's local variable if you want it to be accessible anywhere inside the class it must be an instance variable

also don't use `Data(contentsOf: url)` because it blocks main thread , download it in a background queue then show it in the main queue Or simply use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) after pod installation use

```
let url = URL(string: article.imageURL)!
cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: how would one do that

Comment: click the attached link , add the pod to your pods file create if not using , install , and write the above line inside **cellForRowAt**

Comment: I installed the pods but it won't let me import SDWebImage for some reason

Comment: open the project from workspace , wait until processing finishes

Comment: the function is not working for me, the url gets passed perfectly fine to the sd_setImage function but it does not set the image, any idea what could be happening?

Comment: make sure enable arbitrary loads got http/https requests in plist

Comment: im allowing arbitrary loads but don't see anything about http/https requests